# SHA256 Algorithm

Tags: apex, crypto

I have to apply SHA256 algorithm to a string. As the Salesforce [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SHA256.htm) says, I have used the method `SHA256('myString', 'UTF-8')` and its giving an error as 'Method not exists'

Comment: Are you trying to do it via Apex or in Marketing Cloud? They are entirely different technologies.

Answer (score 4):

Adrian's answer was very helpful in pointing me in the right direction, but the response is

```
System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string
```

There is something in the blob returned by Crypto.generateDigest() that is not UTF-8.

Thanks to Mohith Shrivastava at https://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2014/01/encrypting-xml-response-from-external.html I was able to convert to hex to get a valid string output:

```
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueOf('Come on you mighty port');
Blob mySha = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', myBlob);
//String myString = mySha.toString(); - Generates 'BLOB is not valid UTF-8'
String myHex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(mySha);
System.debug(myHex);
// Converting hex back to string generates 'BLOB is not valid UTF-8' again
//String myString = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(myHex).toString();
```

In my use case, the content of the string is not important, I'm just looking to create a consistent, unique string from a longer string so as not to exced 255 char limit.

See docs:

Blob Class:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm?search_text=crypto%20class#apex_methods_system_blob

Crypto Class:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm?search_text=crypto%20class#apex_classes_restful_crypto

EncodingUtil Class:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm?search_text=crypto%20class#apex_classes_restful_encodingutil

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `String` hash of another `String`, you need to use the **`Crypto`** class, specifically the `generateDigest` method:

> **generateDigest(algorithmName, input)**
>   Computes a secure, one-way hash digest based on the supplied input string and algorithm name.
>
> **Signature**
>
> ```
> public static Blob generateDigest(String algorithmName, Blob input)
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   *algorithmName*
>   Type: String
>   Valid values for algorithmName are:
>
> - MD5
> - SHA1
> - SHA-256
> - SHA-512
>
> *input*
>   Type: Blob
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Blob
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Blob targetBlob = Blob.valueOf('ExampleMD5String');
> Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', targetBlob);
> ```

So if you need to go `String` to `String`, it would look something like:

```
public static String getSha256(String input)
{
    return Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(input)).toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrian.Blob to blob is working fine.But for string ,it giving a error as Blob.valueOf() is not a valid method

Comment: Did you name one of your variables somewhere `blob`?